# Section with RootElement inside

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I'm new to iOS app development, Xamarin/Xcode, and Monotouch.dialog. I'm trying to do the example under "More on Sections and RootElements: RootElements" (http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/) to get myself acquainted with MonoTouch.Dialog for a multi-screen app for work. MonoTouch.Dialog seems simple, but I'm running into an inexplicable problem (q2).

So here're my questions/problems:

1. How do I integrate a MonoTouch.Dialog created page inside a multi-screen application that uses non-table screens? Do I have to create a NavigationController inside the main NavigationController [e.g. -> (NavigationController) - Home - SomethingElse - (NavigationController) - (Monotouch.Dialog created pages)], and how do I connect the beginning page and the MonoTouch.Dialog pages?
2. Working in Xamarin-iOS, I have done everything the example describes, and watched numerous videos, and read several Xamarin documentations of MonoTouch.dialog, but when I click the created element rows (the rows under the "Dinner" section), they do not go to the new RootElement that is behind the row. What am I doing wrong? I created a new DialogViewController project, and this is all that I've edited in the Xamarin code inside the AppDelegate.cs (Xcode storyboard only contains a NavigationController).

   ```
   UIWindow _window;
   UINavigationController _nav;
   DialogViewController _rootVC;
   RootElement _rootElement;


   public override UIWindow Window {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   {

       _window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);


       _rootElement = new RootElement ("Meals") {
           new Section ("Dinner") {
               (Element)new RootElement ("Dessert", new RadioGroup ("dessert", 2)) {
                       new Section () {
                           new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "dessert"),
                           new RadioElement ("Milkshake", "dessert"),
                           new RadioElement ("Chocolate Cake", "dessert")
                       }
               },
               (Element)new RootElement ("Something"){
                   new Section () {
                       new EntryElement ("Name", "Click to edit", "")
                   }
               }
           }// end "Dinner"
       }; //end "Meals"


       _rootVC = new DialogViewController (_rootElement);
       _nav = new UINavigationController (_rootVC);
       _window.RootViewController = _nav;
       _window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

       return true;
   } //end FinishedLaunching
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.  I'm not clear where your Storyboard comes into play - there is no need for it when all of your UI is declared in the code.

You only need one `NavigationController` in a "stack".  If your first page was just a `UIViewController` contained within a `NavigationController` with some buttons on it, you could wire up the Touch event of one of your buttons to push your `MonoTouch.Dialog` UI onto the stack

```
  protected void ButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    dvc = new DialogViewController(_root);

    // every view controller has a NavigationController property that will be non-null
    // if that VC is contained within a Nav Controller
    NavigationController.PushViewController(dvc,true);

  }
```

Likewise, from within your `MonoTouch.Dialog` UI you could have a `StringElement` whose Tapped event creates a new instance of a custom view controller class and pushes it onto the navigation stack.